# Formatting user input in Google spreadsheet to a Date

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets

I am writing a short code for my Google spreadsheet that will allow me to organize some data. The code that I wrote works, but it is not letting me compare dates to other dates. For example, I need the input to be compared to some other date. (i.e. if userInputDate < 04/21/2014, then do something). This is what I have:

```
var userInputDate = Browser.inputBox('Start Date', 'Enter start date', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
```

It is not letting me compare the dates. I'm not sure if I have to format the input first in order to be able to see if its bigger than or less than another date. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this Javascript? Why is there a Java tag?

Comment: I was told that some of the code is same as javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting the return value as a date?

If you are doing simple date comparisons it should work fine.  Here's some example code to help illustrate:

```
var d1 = new Date(Browser.inputBox('Start Date', 'Enter first date', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL));
var d2 = new Date(Browser.inputBox('Start Date', 'Enter second date', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL));
Logger.log(d1+(d1<d2)?" < ":" > " +d2);
```

The first (and second) line creates a new variable, and sets it to the value of the user's input (from Browser.inputBox()), treated as a date object (making all the java date methods usable on it)

the last line outputs to the log: **the value of d1** (the appropriate < > symbol, determined by the IF THEN ELSE statement, explained below) **the value of d2**

```
(d1<d2)?" < ":" > "
```

This is an if x then y else z statement.   I evaluates to IF d1 "is less than" d2, THEN output " < " ELSE output " > "  (Yes, " > " will output when d1 = d2).

Comment: Can u elaborate more on the Logger.log part? I am not sure what all of that does. The date format I use is mm/DD/yyyy or mm/DD/yy. Thanks

Comment: It outputs whatever you want to the log (accessible in the Script IDE in View>Logs from the menu bar, or control+enter).  It's very handy for debugging or just keeping an eye on the behavior of the script.  If you keep your script window up, it will show the log results from the last run of the script (for example, if it runs a 10 minute timer)